# Unix help to extract/print 50 lines after every 3rd occurrence pattern till end of file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, command

I need help with extract/print 4 lines after every 3rd occurrence pattern till end of file. Consider below is example of log file

```
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Extract line 1
Extract line 2
Extract line 3
Extract line 4

ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Extract line 5
Extract line 6
Extract line 7
Extract line 8

ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Extract line 9
Extract line 10
Extract line 11
Extract line 12
```

Comment: And ... what is the pattern? what output do you want?

Comment: just skip the lines which start with `ERROR`, `awk '!/^ERROR/' file` to remove the blank lines `awk '!/^ERROR/&&!/^$/' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some flags to keep track of what appeared and how many times:

```
awk -v patt="ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"
    'lines==3 {print; appeared++}
     appeared==4 {lines=0;appeared=0}
     patt~$0 {lines++}' file
```

#### Explanation

This keeps loading `lines` as number of lines matched. Once it has reached `3`, starts printing. It prints exactly `4` times.

- `-v patt="ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"` this provides the pattern to be looked at
- `lines==3 {print; appeared++}` if the counter `lines` is `3`, print the line and start counting how many lines have appeared.
- `appeared==4{lines=0;appeared=0}` if the number of lines that have been printed is already `4`, reset the flags to `0`.
- `patt~$0 {lines++}` if the line matches the pattern given, increment the variable `lines`.

Note all these constants `3` and `4` could be put outside with `-v` as well, to make it more generic:

```
awk -v patt="ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" -v matches=3 -v lines_to_print=4
    'lines==matches {print; appeared++}
     appeared==lines_to_print {lines=0;appeared=0}
     patt~$0 {lines++}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ awk -v patt="ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" 'lines==3 {print; appeared++} appeared==4 {lines=0;appeared=0} patt~$0 {lines++}' file
Extract line 1
Extract line 2
Extract line 3
Extract line 4
Extract line 5
Extract line 6
Extract line 7
Extract line 8
Extract line 9
Extract line 10
Extract line 11
Extract line 12
```

Comment: awk -v patt="ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" 'lines==3 {print; appeared++} appeared==4{lines=0;appeared=0} $0~patt {lines++}' WSPRD33F-website.2014-09-24.log
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Are you in Solaris? If so, run `awk` like this: `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`

Comment: Original question I posted did answer and it worked but log file is more complex than I posted here. That's my bad. Thankss to fedorqui.  ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: I will post it as new question basically ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  can come anywhere in between so I need to have stop pattern and extract line between them from 3rd occurrence...thanks for answer.

Comment: If I neeed 70 lines to be printed, do I just need to change appeared=70 which outside of braces?

Comment: @user4099249 yes, exactly. See the improved version of the answer, with some explanations.