# Unix help to print 50 lines after every 3rd occurrence pattern till end of file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I need help with extract/print lines till stop pattern. This needs to happen after every 3rd occurrence of start pattern and continue till end of file. Consider below is an example of the log file.
my start pattern will be every 3rd occurrence of ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and stop pattern will be Stop_pattern

```
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
Extract line 1
Extract line 2
Extract line 3
Stop_pattern
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
Extract line 5
Extract line 6
Extract line 7
Stop_pattern
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
Extract line 9
Extract line 10
Extract line 11
Stop_pattern
```

desired output:

```
Extract line 1
Extract line 2
Extract line 3
Extract line 5
Extract line 6
Extract line 7
Extract line 9
Extract line 10
Extract line 11
```

Comment: What about the `some text` lines there? Also isn't this essentially just a duplicate of your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144033/unix-help-to-extract-print-50-lines-after-every-3rd-occurrence-pattern-till-end)? (Though the stop condition has changed but if that's all the difference you should link to (and include the script from) the other question.

Comment: some text will be some junk text in log which will be there. its not duplicate.

Comment: I meant should the `some text` lines be in the output? The question makes it sound like they should but the desired output block doesn't have them. And how is it not a duplicate? It is the same question but with a different condition on when to end? You even used almost the same title. A title, I will add, which doesn't match with the contents of the question here with respect to ending condition.

Comment: I got what you're saying, there won't be some text after 3rd occurrence of ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND so it won't be part of output

Comment: Then you need to fix your example input because there is some there. And you still didn't explain how this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND/{:a;$!{N;s//&/3;Ta;n;N;N;p}}' file
```

This gathers up lines until it finds 3  strings and then prints the next 3 lines.

Comment: Sorry I don't have GNU sed

Comment: Using some newlines or perhaps some semi-colons in the script and it should work with standard (non-GNU) `sed`.  The `Ta` may not work without a newline after it; the `p` and the following `}` may both need a semicolon after it.